# Nuget Package Manager: "...is not a valid JSON object"

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, package-managers, nuget-package-manager-console

I setup a Nexus repo recently. I see the expected result if I type the URL into a browser:
[image]

I've successfully added this nuget server as a source to my VS2022 package manager on one machine. On my other machine, however (also with VS2022 installed), I get an error when trying to browse this repo in the package manager:

```
Error  [sourcename] Unable to load the service index for source [url].
The content at '[url]' is not a valid JSON object.
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

It looks like the package manager is expecting JSON, but the nuget server is sending XML. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On Windows in configuration AppData/Roaming/Nuget/Nuget.config remove protocol version or change to 2 for your feed. Probably you have protocolVersion="3".

Comment: That fixes it! I removed the protocol version from that element instead of changing to "2"  since none of my other package sources specify a protocol version. Thanks - SP

Comment: I also deleted the protocol version, restarted VS and everything worked just fine

Comment: does anyone know why fails with protocol3, any ideas ?